# How do i define $ in my Js Query

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to run a JQuery to perform a fixed scroll so that the page can scroll up but fix my a portion of my page at the top. Below is the Jquery, css and HTML i used. Please can someone tell me what i am doing wrong??

> JQuery Error Message: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

HTML:

House of ribs: La Mango

```
              <div>
              <nav id="main-nav">
                  <ul>
                      <li>
                          <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>
                          Find a Hangout Spot
                      </li>
                  </ul>
              </nav>
              </div>
              <span id="mine"></span>
```

CSS:

```
ul{
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 20px 5px 20px;
  list-style-type: none;
  background: #EF5350;
}
ul li{
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.fixed-nav{
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0;
}
```

JQuery:

```
var offset = $('#main-nav').offset();
$(window).scroll(function(){
   //$('#mine').text($(document).scrollTop());
  $('#main-nav').addClass('fixed-nav');
  if($(document).scrollTop() < 10){
         $('#main-nav').removeClass('fixed-nav');
  }
});
```

Comment: is this a wordpress page ( or similar cms that uses noConflict)? Or did you forget to include jQuery.js in page? Or did you include your code before jQuery.js?

Comment: did you import jquery.js files to your project or did you link those online to your project.please put your whole html code

Answer (score 1):

First check if Jquery has been included, and if you're using prototype (Magento uses it) or other library that uses `$` wrap all your jquery code withing an IIFE so you can use `$` safely within.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
```

Javascript

```
(function($){ //$ is now jQuery

  var offset = $('#main-nav').offset();
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    //$('#mine').text($(document).scrollTop());
    $('#main-nav').addClass('fixed-nav');
    if($(document).scrollTop() < 10){
         $('#main-nav').removeClass('fixed-nav');
    }
  });

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a different symbol than `$` for call jQuery functions and objects, but first of all check that jQuery is loaded properly.

I generally use this function to evade the problem of `$` symbol being used by other libraries:

```
var jj = jQuery.noConflict(); //Now use jj instead of $ to call jQuery things
jj("p").css("color", "red");
```